# Is there any way to include a file with a bang (!) in the path in a genrule?

Tags: bazel

I've got an iOS framework that has a dependency on the (presumably Google maintained) pod called '!ProtoCompiler'. In order to build my framework I'm going to need it in the sandbox. So, I have a genrule and can try to include it with

`src = glob(['Pods/!ProtoCompiler/**/*'])` but I get the following error:

> ERROR: BUILD:2:1: //Foo:framework-debug: invalid label 'Pods/!ProtoCompiler/google/protobuf/any.proto' in element 1118 of attribute 'srcs' in 'genrule' rule: invalid target name 'Pods/!ProtoCompiler/google/protobuf/any.proto': target names may not contain '!'.

As is, this seems like a total blocker for me using bazel to do this build. I don't have the ability to rename the pod directory as far as I can tell. As far as I can tell, the ! prohibition is supposed to be for *target* labels, is there any way I can specify that this is just a file, not a label? Or are those two concepts completely melded in bazel?

(Also, if I get this to work I'm worried about the fact that this produces a .framework directory and it seems like rules are expected to produces files only. Maybe I'll zip it up and then unzip it as part of the build of the test harness.)

Comment: Thankfully, those pods are not required at build time so I think I dodged this bullet. I'd still love to know if there is an answer, though. Seems wrong to apply the bazel package/target rules to all file paths in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, the ! prohibition is supposed to be for target
>   labels, is there any way I can specify that this is just a file, not a
>   label? Or are those two concepts completely melded in bazel?

They are mostly molded.

Bazel associates a label with all source files in a package that appear in BUILD files, so that you can write `srcs=["foo.cc", "//bar:baz.cc"]` in a build rule and it'll work regardless of `foo.cc` and `baz.cc` being a source file, a generated file, or a build rule's name that produces files suitable for this particular `srcs` attribute.

That said you can of course have any file in the package, but if the name won't allow Bazel to derive a label from it, then you can't reference them in the BUILD file. Since `glob` is evaluated during loading and is expanded to a list of labels, using `glob` won't work around this limitation.

> (...) it seems like rules are expected to produces files only. Maybe
>   I'll zip it up and then unzip it as part of the build of the test
>   harness.

Yes, that's the usual approach.

Comment: By "you can have any file in the package" do you mean simply that a directory containing a BUILD file can contain files with whatever name you like? I appreciate that this won't crash bazel, but in order to perform *any* operation in bazel build you must actually reference the file in a BUILD file somewhere, no?

Comment: You're right on both accounts. Yes, that's what I meant -- that merely having files in the package that Bazel couldn't work with doesn't crash Bazel or render it inoperable, which is pretty basic but I wanted to point it out anyway. Alas to make anything useful with those files you indeed would need to reference them somehow.